# Sequential read/write to DB by chaining promises using Cloud Functions and Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a project that requires me to upload data to firebase real-time database and perform some manipulations using cloud functions. The operations need to happen sequentially, one after the other, and so I am chaining JavaScript promises.

As I'm new to JavaScript, I don't quite understand the concept of promises and I'm getting errors when I try to deploy the code. I'd come up with this code based on my primitive understanding of JS. If there's a better way of achieving this, please let me know.

Here's the code snippet:

```
var initialWaterHeight, currentWaterHeight, waterUsedBeforeTankFill, usageTracking;
var promise1, promise2;
exports.setMotor = functions.database.ref('BORE Tank/Depth')
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    var currentWaterHeight = snapshot.before.val;
    const levelChange = snapshot.before.val - snapshot.after.val;
    const time = new Date(Date.now() + 19800000).toLocaleString();
    if (levelChange >= 0.2)
    {
        promise1 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('Motor').set(1) ;
    }
    else
    {
        promise1 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('Motor').set(0) ;
    }
    promise2 = snapshot.after.ref.parent.child('Time').set(time);
    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
}).then( () => {
    functions.database.ref('BORE Tank/Motor')
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
        if (snapshot.before.val === 0 && snapshot.after.val === 1)
        {
            admin.database().ref('BORE Tank/waterUsedBeforeTankFill')
            .once('value', function(snap) {
                waterUsedBeforeTankFill = snap.val();
            });
            admin.database().ref('BORE Tank/initialWaterHeight')
            .once('value', function(snap){
                initialWaterHeight = snap.val();
            });
            promise1 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('usageTracking').set(0);
            promise2 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('waterUsedBeforeTankFill')
            .set(waterUsedBeforeTankFill + Math.abs((initialWaterHeight - currentWaterHeight)));
            return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
        }
    else if (snapshot.before.val === 1 && snapshot.after.val === 0)
    {
        promise1 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('usageTracking').set(1);
        promise2 = snapshot.ref.parent.child('initialWaterHeight').set(currentWaterHeight);
        return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
    }
});
return null;
}).then(() =>{
    admin.database().ref('BORE Tank/usageTracking')
    .once('value', function (snap){
        usageTracking = snap.val();
    });
    if (usageTracking)
    {
        return admin.database.ref('BORE Tank/usage')
        .set(waterUsedBeforeTankFill + Math.abs((initialWaterHeight - currentWaterHeight)));
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you asking about how to fix your errors, or are you asking a broader question about how promises work?

Answer (score 0):

Promises are an alternative to callbacks. They improve readability, simplify error handling, and decouple tasks into composable units. A Promise is a task that may not have finished yet. When a Promise's task finishes successfully the Promise is "fulfilled", otherwise it is "rejected." You interact with a Promise by calling its then method with callbacks that should be executed when the Promise is fulfilled or rejected.

You can review more information about Firebase and JavaScript promises here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html